# Ironpython console disappears instantly

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, ironpython

I installed ironpython 2.0 in the windows xp professional box and it requires .Net framework 2.0 service pack 2 or later. The windows box has it. But still the console disappears. There is issue in either of them.

Need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the way....

.NET 2.0 and .Net 3.0 do not have SP1.

So either version of .Net with SP1 will make Ironpython work...yippee

Answer (score 1):

The same result

Iropython requires .NET 2.0 sp1 or later

There is no error infact...

I suppose Ironpython is not finding the .Net libraries where it is supposed to be.

If the control panel\Add remove programs shows the .Net framework, does this mean they are installed. I am asking this question coz in forums no body has talked about checking the control panel thing; however, they either talk about checking Registry or %systemroot%\Microsoft .net\Framework and check for Mscorlib.dll  in the respective version folder.

Well, I have found the .dll file for .net 2.0 and .net 1.1  but not for .net 3.0 
If .net 3.0 is not installed, then the reason for failure of ironpython is sp1 for .net 2.0 is not installed.

Also, i checked the registry information at 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\policy\v2.0
and found that .NEt 2.0, the orignal version is installed

however, I found .net 3.0 in .NETFramework folder, but not in policy folder. And in that folder, there is no such folder like v3.0 where the value is set such and such.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you open a command prompt and run ipy from there?

Run (From the command prompt) ipy -X:ExceptionDetail
This will hopefully give more info.

Also have a look in the  Windows Event Log (Application) for any errors related to IPY.

**Update** If you have no error recorded, try running another .Net program to see if it is a general problem. Uninstalling the Framework and reinstalling the Framework would be the next step to try.

Cheers,

Davy